# I would like to see the rails application in elastic beanstalk, but I can be angry at the ruby ​version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to see the rails application in elastic beanstalk, but I can be angry at the ruby ​​version.
However, no description of 2.4.1 can be found anywhere.
What kind of problem do you think?

```sh
Creating application version archive "xxx".
Uploading xxx.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2019-06-17 12:33:43    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2019-06-17 12:33:49    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2019-06-17 12:33:57    ERROR   [Instance: xxx] Command failed on instance. Return code: 18 Output: (TRUNCATED)...e ']'
+ bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2019-06-17 12:33:57    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2019-06-17 12:33:57    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'xxx'. Aborting the operation.
2019-06-17 12:33:57    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

```
ruby '2.6.3'
```

local ruby version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]

Elastic Beanstalk
Puma with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.5

Answer (score 0):

The Elastic Beanstalk instance is set up to use Ruby 2.6, but in the `Gemfile` in the root of your application, you have a line like:

```rb
# Gemfile

ruby '2.4.1'
```

which declares that you are using Ruby 2.4.1.

You need to either change the Ruby version to '2.6.3' in the Gemfile and re-run `bundle install` to update the `Gemfile.lock` version, or you need to recreate your Elastic Beanstalk environment using the Ruby 2.4 version platform.  If you recreate the Elastic Beanstalk environment, they may use a different patch version of Ruby 2.4, so you may have to update your Gemfile to match the Ruby version that Elastic Beanstalk is using anyway.

Comment: I understand the cause. The information on the github master is 2.4.1.
I used ruby ​​2.6.3 in Gemfile, but I did not commit it to master, and it was the behavior for EB to see 2.4.1.
Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the Ruby version listed twice, once as 2.4.1, and once as 2.6.3?